# Re-triangulate points (in CGAL) every step

Tags: simulation, cgal, triangulation

I want to simulate a system of particles for N steps. In every step, periodioc triangulation of these points is constructed. In every step coordinates of particles change, So, I need to remove (or delete) triangulation of the previous step and make a new one. From searching the manual, I just found this function:

**void     remove (Vertex_handle v)**
and tried this:

```
typedef Triangulation::Vertex_iterator Vi;
for(int istep=0; istep<N_step; istep++)

    {\\make triangulation
    Triangulation T(points.begin(), points.end(), domain);

    \\some parts of the code which change array of *points*
    for (Vi vi = T.vertices_begin(); vi != T.vertices_end(); vi++){

    Vertex_handle v = vi;

    T.remove(v);\\remove triangulation by removing vertices
            }
     }
```

but this leads to **segmentation fault.** There is N vertex, and segmentation fault is for removing (N+1)th vertex!!! ), maybe this is due to the periodic nature of triangulation.

Now, I have two question: 1) how to remove vertices in periodic triangulation by **remove()** function?

2) Isn't there another efficient way to remove previous triangulation and create new one?

**EDIT**: the code bellow, contains main part of the code, and shows what I'm going to do:

```
//--------------

#include <cstdlib>       
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>        
#include <vector>
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Periodic_2_Delaunay_triangulation_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Periodic_2_triangulation_traits_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_2.h>

using namespace std;

//******************CGAL_prerequisite************************/
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel Kernel;
typedef CGAL::Periodic_2_triangulation_traits_2<Kernel> Gt;
typedef CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_2<unsigned int, Gt> Vb;
typedef CGAL::Periodic_2_triangulation_face_base_2<Gt> Fb;
typedef CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<Vb, Fb> Tds;
typedef CGAL::Periodic_2_Delaunay_triangulation_2<Gt, Tds> Triangulation;

typedef Triangulation::Point Point;
typedef Triangulation::Edge_iterator Edge_iterator;
typedef Triangulation::Vertex_handle Vertex_handle;
typedef Triangulation::Vertex_circulator Vertex_circulator;
typedef Triangulation::Iso_rectangle Iso_rectangle;
typedef Triangulation::Vertex_iterator Vi;

typedef std::vector<std::pair<Point, unsigned> > Vector;

/*********************Simulation_parameters*****************/
const int N = 16;            
double L = 4;        //linear size of the square 
double S = 0.5;         //0.5
double dt = 1.0;        
int N_step = 100;

ofstream output("traj_2D.xyz");

int main(){

Iso_rectangle domain(0,0,L,L);

Vector points;

vector<vector<double> > dir;\\an array for 2D velocities of each particle
dir.resize(N);
for(int i=0; i<N; i++){dir[i].resize(2);}

vector<vector<double> > pos;\\an array for 2D initial positions
pos.resize(N);
for(int i=0; i<N; i++){pos[i].resize(2);}


/*****initialize_positions*****/
\\some part of the code
/*****initialize_velocities*****/
\\some part of the code   


  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
       points.push_back(make_pair(Point(pos[i][0], pos[i][1]), i));  

/********************************************************************
*********************************************************************/

for(int istep = 0; istep < N_step; istep++)
     {
      Triangulation T(points.begin(), points.end(), domain); 


      \\update positions and apply periodic boundary conditons
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {

             points[i].first = Point(points[i].first.x()+S*dir[i][0]*dt , points[i].first.y()+S*dir[i][1]*dt);


            // use periodic boundary conditions
            if (points[i].first.x() < 0)
                points[i].first=Point(points[i].first.x()+L, points[i].first.y());
            if (points[i].first.y() < 0)
                points[i].first=Point(points[i].first.x(), points[i].first.y()+L);
            if (points[i].first.x() > L)
                points[i].first=Point(points[i].first.x()-L, points[i].first.y());
            if (points[i].first.y() > L)
                points[i].first=Point(points[i].first.x(), points[i].first.y()+L);

                                 }
          \\write the updated positions to a file
            for(int s = 0;s < N;s++){
             output<<points[s].first.x()<<"  "<<points[s].first.y()<<"  "<<"0.0"<<endl;}
     T.clear();
                 }    
return 0;}
//*****************************************************************************************************
```

Comment: Like any container, you cannot remove an element and expect its iterator to be valid. The increment must be done before removing the element.

Comment: There is a `clear()` function to remove all simplices.

Comment: Thank you. `Clear()` removes all vertices, and now T.number_of_vertices= 0;     But when the program goes to the next step in the loop, `Triangulation T(points.begin(), points.end(), domain);`  produces: Segmentation fault (core dumped)!!!

Comment: If you don't post a complete program it is hard to help. The constructor of a triangulation can only be called once. If you called clear() on the triangulation then obviously you cannot recreate it. It is hard to guess what you did.

Comment: Thank you, please take a look at my code in  the **edited** part of the quastion.

Comment: Calling `clear()` is useless since the triangulation will be recreated. I don't see anything suspect. If this segfault for `istep=1`, I suggest that you increase the precision of `output` (`output.precision(17);`), try to read back the file and build a triangulation out of it. If you still observe an error, then submit a bug report [here](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/issues)

Comment: I added these lines to the end of my code, and the error still exist :( `output.precision(17);
            for(int s = 0;s < N;s++){
             output<<points[s].first.x()<<"\t"<<points[s].first.y()<<endl;}
                 

ifstream in("traj_2D.xyz");
istream_iterator<Point> begin(in);
istream_iterator<Point> end;
Triangulation TRI;
TRI.insert(begin, end);`

Comment: Then post the file somewhere we can try to reproduce the issue

Comment: I realized that one of the points' y coordinate lay out of the box! and that was the origin of seg-fault. thanks for the usefull comments.